# WPF For Beginners Clarification

Tags: asp.net, wpf, webforms

I am a Web developer in ASP.Net. Just I heard about WPF.Is WPF is for Desktop stuff or can
i use all WPF controls in my web application?. When i visit the microsoft website it talsk much about  designer tools (expression,blend),where can i get web developer perspective vidoes of WPF (Just drag the control on my form and set the properties for coding)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bottom line is this - WPF is a desktop technology. It's very closely related sibling - Silverlight requires a runtime much like Flash to run in the browser.

Silverlight components/controls/applications can be hosted inside of an asp.net application but the idea that your skills will just 'carry over' is grossly misguided. Silverlight uses the same core languages (C#, VB.NET etc and a subset of the .NET Framework) so to that extent that knowledge is valuable but both WPF and Silverlight use a declarative presentation language called XAML or (XML Application Markup Language). XAML is what HTML can only dream to be - it is extremely powerful and elegant and has rich support for things like binding.

From a tooling perspective - Expression Blend is really a XAML designer that can target Silverlight or WPF applications.

Videos can be found at

- http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx
- http://silverlight.net/learn/
- http://microsoftpdc.com/Videos

UPDATE: Ray makes some good points in the comments section about WPF controls and the XBAP type (Xaml Browser Applications)

Comment: This answer has some good information but I fear it is also highly misleading.  The question asked "Is WPF for Desktop stuff or can i use all WPF controls in my web application?"  In point of fact, WPF has a very good web deployment capability called XBAP, so it is certainly not desktop-only technology.  I have created several web applications using all WPF controls.  Of course Silverlight may be more appropriate in many scenarios, but I think you should edit your answer to clarify that WPF itself can deploy to both the desktop and the web.

Comment: "XAML is what HTML can only dream to be" - Nice!

Comment: Ray - point taken on the XBAP stuff but I think when most people talk about putting stuff into their web apps they are usually talking about in-lining them as Html output elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing intranet applications, you might also consider WPF XBAPs(XAML Broswer applications). Clickonce enables very interesting deployment scenarios of WPF XBAPs in intranet environment.

WPF XBAPs can provide more features than silverlight because XBAPs can make use of full .NET framework. Having said that silverlight is really amazing for developing Line Of Business applications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You **CAN** use WPF for your web application.  I have done so on several occasions.

To deploy WPF to a web browser you wrap your content in Page controls and create what is called an XAML Browser Application ("XBAP").  XBAPs can do almost everything that a full WPF application can do except access the local computer and call unmanaged code.

At present XBAPs are significantly more powerful than Silverlight, though that gap is closing quickly.  I expect in another year or two Silverlight will be as good as XBAP for web deployment.

Answer (score 0):

WPF is solely for desktop applications. Silverlight is very similar to WPF however and can be used as a Flash replacement, so your skills carry over.

Comment: it should be kept in mind that silverlight is a sub-set of wpf, and due to the security model there are some things you just can't (or shouldn't) do with silverlight.

Comment: Incorrect.  WPF is not solely for desktop applications.  WPF can be deployed to either the desktop or the web.  I have created some extremely impressive web applications in a short timeframe and everyone asks me how I did it.  My secret weapon is WPF, which at this point is still more powerful than Silverlight.  Of course you miss out on the 10% of the market that is not running Windows but with Silverlight improving in leaps and bounds, I think we will soon be able to switch over (Markup extensions, please!).

Comment: I don't count XBAPs because they're hard to get right (signing, full vs. partial trust, browser issues, etc...), but you are right

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for WPF beginner videos to start with, then try these:

http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx

Hope, it will be helpful.